# Looking for correct vocabulary

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, vocabulary

Tea cultivation is very popular in some country. It generally follows step cultivation. If I want to express areas where tea is cultivated what would be best way to express the areas. Is that tea cultivation land or tea bed? Is there any word like tea bed?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend "tea plantation".

Comment: Farm might also work depending on the situation, but plantation is a much better word.